# cannot print from flash-player plugin

Tags: linux, firefox, plugins, printing, flash-player

I am running flash-player plug-in 10.0.32.10 inside of Firefox on a SLED 11 machine.

Firefox can print to the network printer without issue from File > Print.

However, I cannot get the flash-player plugin to print at all.  The print dialog comes up, asks for which printer, and which pages.  I click Print and it was as if I had pressed cancel.

Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found evidence that this is a known issue in the flash-player plugin.

I found two bugs filed against Adobe Flash Player that are directly related:

- [FP-1853](https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-1853)
- [FP-2807](https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-2807)

I also found a bug filed against Ubuntu, posted months earlier than the bugs listed above:

- [Bug 275691](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/flashplugin-nonfree/+bug/275691)

In short, **this is a known issue** with the Firefox flash-player plugin under Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Well for once, update Flash, its now like 10.0.42 or something of that sort. Also you could try up or downgrading Firefox.

And lastly if neither of those work, either save the page for offline use and try that. Or Take a screenshot and print the screenshot.

EDIT: just curious, Gnome or KDE, i don't know if that will make a difference, but it could.

Comment: Gnome...15 char